# Integrate multiple instances of java desktop application with online accounting (quickbooks, peachtree)

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am writing a java desktop application which will connect to a server and pull various data products.  Customers will be charged a 'per-click' fee (i.e. Sally at Acme pulls a data report costing $5 anywhere from 1 to several thousand times per day -- I want her name, customer ID, product price, date/time, etc. sent to quickbooks or peachtree each time she does this).  So we could potentially have anywhere from 10 to eventually several hundred instances of this application out there.

Anyone have any suggestions as to how I might approach this?  I want to use ONLY java so ideally there would be an api out there for quickbooks or peachtree that would allow for this integration.

Thanks!!!
Marc

Answer (score 0):

I think more detail is needed.  The first problem is what application is Sally pulling a report from, if it is in Quickbooks online, how will you get that information from the website to your application.  Why do you want to write that information to Quickbooks.  Writing to an independent database may be easier.  It sounds like there may be some security concerns with what you are trying to do, that may be difficult to overcome in the browser.

Comment: It is not a web application.  It is a desktop application.  At no time is a browser involved.  Reports are just proprietary data pulled from a data provider - not from quickbooks.  Every time a report is pulled though - the fact that one has been pulled along with price etc. is what I want to send to quickbooks.